# value more than not read in if condition in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I m getting two textboxes value as 5 and 10.

so i m validating them on the following if condition

```
var textboxvalue1 = $('#textboxvalue1' + counter).val();
var textboxvalue2 = $('#textboxvalue2' + counter).val();
if (textboxvalue1 < textboxvalue2) {
    alert("error");
}
textboxvalue1 = 10
textboxvalue2 = 5
```

its showing an alert in this case.which it shud nt show.bt when textboxvalue1 is less than 10,it works fine.

Comment: string comparison happening, perhaps ... jQueery .val() possibly returns a string ... try `var textboxvalue1=parseFloat($('#textboxvalue1'+counter).val());`

Answer (score 4):

Actually your `.val()` returns string you try to convert it as integer so use **parseInt()** in your context and check.

**The parseInt() function parses a string and returns an integer.**

**Note**:

> The radix parameter is used to specify which numeral system to be
>   used, for example, a radix of 16 (hexadecimal) indicates that the
>   number in the string should be parsed from a hexadecimal number to a
>   decimal number.
>
> If the radix parameter is omitted, JavaScript assumes the following:
>
> If the string begins with "0x", the radix is 16 (hexadecimal) If the
>   string begins with "0", the radix is 8 (octal). This feature is
>   deprecated If the string begins with any other value, the radix is 10
>   (decimal)

```
var textboxvalue1= parseInt($('#textboxvalue1'+counter).val(), 10);
var textboxvalue2= parseInt($('#textboxvalue2'+counter).val(), 10);

if (textboxvalue1 < textboxvalue2) {
    alert("error");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert your input strings to numbers like this:

```
var textboxvalue1=parseInt($('#textboxvalue1'+counter).val());
var textboxvalue2=parseInt($('#textboxvalue2'+counter).val());
```

Answer (score 0):

The values are being interpreted as strings by JavaScript, not numbers. Wrap them in `parseInt` or `parseFloat` before comparing them.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ParseInt` Because `var` return string default. Or you can use `parseFloat`

```
var textboxvalue1= parseInt($('#textboxvalue1'+counter).val(), 10);
var textboxvalue2= parseInt($('#textboxvalue2'+counter).val(), 10);
if (textboxvalue1 < textboxvalue2) {
    alert("error");
}
```